# Join with queryover in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying, without successs, to create a query with QueryOver in NHibernate.
The resulting SQL I need to get is the following:

```
select mn.Story_ID from Membership_Updates mn
join Updates upd on mn.Story_ID = upd.Story_ID
where mn.MembershipUser_ID = 1
group by mn.Story_ID having MAX(mn.DismissTime) <= MAX(upd.CreationDate)
```

My classes:

```
public class MembershipUpdates
{
  public MembershipUpdates()
  {
    DismissTime = DateTime.Now;
  }

  public virtual int Id  { get; set; }
  public virtual MembershipUser User { get; set; }
  public virtual Story Story { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime DismissTime { get; set; }
}

public class Updates 
{
  public Updates()
  {
    CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
  }

  public virtual int Id  { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; private set; }
  public virtual Story Story { get; set; }
  public virtual string Message{ get; set; }
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think QueryOver allows you to join unrelated entities (without resorting to subqueries, that is).

I would use HQL for this:

```
select mn.Story
from MembershipUpdates mn, Updates upd
where upd.Story = upd.Story
and mn.User.id = 1
group by mn.Story
having MAX(mn.DismissTime) <= MAX(upd.CreationDate)
```

Sidenote: your entity class name should be singular.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of that. HQL will be then :)